# Convert column as character into list type with R

Tags: r, regex, type-conversion

I have a CSV file with a column like this:

```
Categories
['Internet', 'Media', 'Platform']
['Platform', 'Business', 'services']
['Smart', 'Contract', 'Platform', 'Health', 'Cryptocurrency', 'Charity']
```

After importing the dataframe using `read.csv`, the class of the column is factor. I need to convert each list into a proper list class.
In the R console I attempted to convert each "value" into a list with `as.list(levels(df$Categories))` and also with

```
for (list in ICOdata$Categories){
    print(as.list(list))
}
```

How can I do the conversion? Is it necessary to do some splitting by `'` and using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can split the column into a `list` with `strsplit` and update the 'Categories'

```
df1$Categories <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$Categories),
                "[][']|,\\s*"), function(x) x[nzchar(x)])
```